# Convert SOAP based to Restful application

Tags: soap, jersey, websphere, ltpa

I have to covert a SOAP based into RESTFul application. We are using IBM websphere and LTPA token for authentication. I have 2 ideas about it.

1. Manually convert into restful application. (Not sure how to integrate LTPA into it)
2. Provide a proxy so that a restful application makes call to soap and fetch response. (Think i don't have to worry about LTPA here)

What am looking for is the easy of use for the end user, so that they don't have to construct the whole xml.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly is the role of LTPA. Are you looking for identity, authentication or authorization. If you want all then you need to think of a way to integrate LTPA and OAuth. You can use the OAuth for making the rest service secure.

You can get some more info here.
http://www.srimax.com/index.php/do-you-need-api-keys-api-identity-vs-authorization/